# Open source license for test code

Tags: unit-testing, open-source, licensing

I'm creating a project to house an iPhone library for common code for the iPhone... essentially it's a library that'll save people from finding solutions to common problems that amount to copying and pasting snippets of code. The site is located here: http://code.google.com/p/devkit-bb/

I licensed it under Eclipse, because fosters the extension of the library without requiring constraints like LGPL on object files being provided/made available, which would be the case since everything is statically linked.

What I'm wondering is how/what license to apply to the unit tests? Since they essentially demonstrate how to use various interfaces and components. Thus they're designed for potential copy and paste situations, and I don't want people who might end up using this as part of the building blocks of their environment to feel like the license would prohibit that "derivative work", ie. their application or game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that scenario, you might want to consider the [MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

Comment: Yah, that might be as close to a standard license as I can get. I'm not sure even what "substantial" might be interpreted as, and even having the copyright notice is somewhat overkill for utilizing sample code provided in a unit-test. I think I was investigating Apache or Mozilla license, and I came across the Open Group license:
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/opengroup.php

What are your thoughts on this? The unfortunate part is there isn't a standard banner to apply on it. I'm hoping I can get Ohloh.net to pick it up.

Comment: The Open Group license is designed for standalone test suites that are themselves a product intended to be used to test a third party's implementation of some standard specified interface.  If they're just unit tests for your implementation, the MIT license is probably appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The [WTFPL](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/), if you can get it past your lawyers.

Comment: Isn't that a derivative of the `bugroff` license? http://www.everything2.com/index.pl?node_id=405239